# Make sidebar div scrollable

Tags: jquery, html, css

**EDIT** I've added overflow-y: auto; to slidable and slide and on doing so the slide button to open the sidebar disappears...

I have a sidebar similar to this one setup in my application but have been having difficulties making the content scrollable when overflow in the y occurs.

As you can see I have content that is not visible as you are unable to scroll to it. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#side").click(function() {
    $('#slidable').toggleClass("open");
  });
})
```

```css
#side {
  position:absolute;
  right:100%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1000000;
  color:black;
}

#slidable {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: black;
  width: 200px;
  left: 100%;
  transition: 0.4s;
  z-index: 1000000;
  color:black;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color:white;
}

#slidable.open{
  left: calc(100% - 200px);
}

.fa {
  font-size:30px!;
  margin-top:25px;
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="slidable" class="slidable">
  <div id="side" class="side icon">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
  <div>
      <p>Sidebar</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        Content that you shouldn't be able to see without scrolling
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content" class="content">
  <p>test here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I added overflow-y: auto for '.slidable' and everything it's okay. Can you give us more info? I'm sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: @hüseyint when i add that the side button to expand the side menu disappears?

Comment: @hüseyint could you link me your js fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the scroll with your current css and markup by adding a class to the content that is supposed to be scrolling, and give that class `height: 100%; overflow: auto;`. You can see it working in the snippet below.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#side").click(function() {
    $('#slidable').toggleClass("open");
  });
})
```

```css
#side {
  position:absolute;
  right:100%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1000000;
  color:black;
}

#slidable {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: black;
  width: 200px;
  left: 100%;
  transition: 0.4s;
  z-index: 1000000;
  color:black;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color:white;
}

#slidable.open{
  left: calc(100% - 200px);
}

.fa {
  font-size:30px!;
  margin-top:25px;
  color:black;
}
.scrollableContent{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="slidable" class="slidable">
  <div id="side" class="side icon">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="scrollableContent">
      <p>Sidebar</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        Content that you shouldn't be able to see without scrolling
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content" class="content">
  <p>test here</p>
</div>
```